# Having error upon trying to parse a JSON array into JSON object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, discord.net

I am trying to parse a JSON array by using this code:

```
public async Task QuoteAsync()
{
    await this.Context.Channel.TriggerTypingAsync();
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var result = await client.GetStringAsync("https://zenquotes.io/api/random");
    JArray qarray = JArray.Parse(result);
    JObject quote = JObject.Parse(qarray[0]["q"].ToString());
    JObject author = JObject.Parse(qarray[0]["a"].ToString());
    await this.ReplyAsync($"{quote} - {author}");
}
```

The response I receive upon sending a request to zenquotes api is

```json
[
  {
    "q": "Be where your enemy is not.",
    "a": "Sun Tzu",
    "h": "<blockquote>&ldquo;Be where your enemy is not.&rdquo; &mdash; <footer>Sun Tzu</footer></blockquote>"
  }
]
```

I can't seem to figure out why the error is occurring since I don't really see any issues.
This is the error I am getting:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: A. Path '', line 0, position 0.

The error is occurring on the 7th line:

```
JObject quote = JObject.Parse(qarray[0]["q"].ToString());
```

and since the 8th line is the same I expect the same error.

Comment: Is the attached JSON is complete JSON result? As your JSON result is not an array but is *single object*.

Comment: copy the string result to any development tools console and test your code.

Comment: @Yong Shun i made a mistake while typing it's actually a json array its enclosed with square brackets

Comment: Hi @ShauryaChauhan, thanks for clarifying. You may update your JSON result as JSON array.

Comment: hi @Yong Shun i see i came to know that I can also deserialize the json array but the answer given is better :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JObject.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm),

> Load a JObject from a string that contains JSON.

For your `"q"` and `"a"`, it is just a **simple** string but **not a JSON string**. Hence you should not use `JObject.Parse`.

With `.ToString()`, it is good enough to retrieve the value of `q` and `a`.

```cs
string quote = qarray[0]["q"].ToString();
string author = qarray[0]["a"].ToString();
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AL9xAX)